# Get the nth element from array_chunk returned results

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very large array which I have split with `array_chunk` into six, I'm looking to get `remove/access` the 5th (all for the price) item in every chunk. Here are 2 of many chunks

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Scottsdale
    [1] => Santa Ana John Wayne Airport
    [2] => Cessna C750 Citation X
    [3] => 8
    [4] => Mon Nov 12 00:00:00 GMT 2018
    [5] => Call for Price (Was $10 980)
)

Array
(
    [0] => Milwaukee Mitchell Intl
    [1] => Chicago Midway International
    [2] => Cessna C750 Citation X
    [3] => 8
    [4] => Mon Nov 12 00:00:00 GMT 2018
    [5] => Call for Price (Was $6 300)
)
```

Comment: `I'm looking to get remove/access the 5th (all for the price) item in every chunk`-> in an array or just want to print through loop?

Comment: `foreach(array_chunk($arr, 6) as $a) { echo $a[5]; }`

Comment: So do you want to access them or remove them?

Comment: I wanted to access them bthatnks i found an easier way

Answer (score 2):

***1.*** If you want to access them and put them into separate array then use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$price_array = array_column($array,5);
print_r($price_array);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/1slp0

***2.*** If you want to access them for printing purpose then use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($array as $arr){

    echo $arr[5].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/NXVEb

***3.*** If you want to remove them then again use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($array as &$arr){

    unset($arr[5]);
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/W5WYO

***4.*** if you want to remove that value from child array as well as want to print then use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) and [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) along with [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    unset($arr[5]);  //this will not remove the value from original array
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($arr);
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/Td4u3

***Reference***:- [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: Thanks i will try it out but i have found another way

Answer (score -4):

I solved it:-

```
foreach ($myrows as $myrows) {
    unset($myrows[5]);  
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($myrows);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Wow you must have tried really hard before posting the question. I mean 10 minutes later you have a working code.

Comment: array_chunk($rows,10,false);

Comment: Very cheeky @Andrea  the reason it dint work i was using array_chunk($rows,10,true); somewhere in the code instead of array_chunk($rows,10,false ); that way i could not get to the item . i changed to false and then pasted the array here before tasting it , then realized the array keys have changed and can easily accessed .